# Tuning the GC for large cache refresh

Tags: java, caching, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

I have a large cache in memory (implemented using `com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache`). This gets refreshed after 10 minutes by using a Scheduler like so:

```
ScheduledExecutorService refresher = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    refresher.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    for (String key : cache.asMap().keySet()) {
                        cache.refresh(key);
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

The problem I am facing is - there's a huge spike in the Old Generation space after every 10 minutes. I am hypothesizing that this is happening because of the refresh taking place and old objects are not being cleared as quickly as new ones are created. This can be seen in the graph below. (Note: this graph shows the CMS GC, but I get the same results with G1GC).

[image]

What are the steps I can take to optimize this specific issue? I can use CMS or G1GC, but these spikes have to be flattened. The reason is, Full GC is getting kicked in and the app is going into `Stop The World GC`.

Is there anything I can do to optimise the code of the cache to refresh it more efficiently so that there are no sudden spikes?

Comment: Your use case is as close to an antipattern as I have ever seen. I would seriously look at going off-heap with something like JChronicle [ChronicleMap](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map)

Comment: Could you please elaborate as to why this is an anti-pattern? And what can be done to by-pass it?

Comment: What does `asMap()` do, create a view of the cache or a copy?

Comment: Since you are doing a time-based reload (guessing from the behaviour shown in the gc log), you are guaranteeing that the cache will have moved into the old gen, so you are deliberately creating old gen memory churn. Remedies would be to move to a event based refresh (ie change the value in the cache only if there is one) or move off-heap.

Comment: And the anti-pattern is using a time based total reload of a cache sized in the multi GB range.

Answer (score 1):

> I am hypothesizing that this is happening because of the refresh taking place and old objects are not being cleared as quickly as new ones are created.

Using an allocation profiler could help testing that hypothesis.

> What are the steps I can take to optimize this specific issue? I can use CMS or G1GC, but these spikes have to be flattened. The reason is, Full GC is getting kicked in and the app is going into Stop The World GC.

A Full GC often indicates that the concurrent part of the collector cannot keep up with the allocation rate. But to verify you should check the GC logs for the Full GC reason.
You can try lowering the IHOP, providing additional CPU cores for concurrent GC work or pacing the refresh tasks so that they're more spread out over the 10 minute interval.

You should also check the GC heuristic logs for mixed collections (assuming G1GC) whether it manages to pick any regions at all for mixed collections. If it goes straight from young collections to a Full GC without any mixed collections then it's possible some other heuristics have issues due to the allocation patterns of your cache.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Regarding your suggestion `pacing the refresh tasks so that they're more spread out over the 10 minute interval.` : Can you suggest how this can be achieved with google guava cache?

Comment: That's not related to what cache you're using, you have to rewrite your schedule/for loop to operate in a way that spreads the items over time.

Answer (score 1):

GC tuning might improve the symptoms a bit, but its better to tackle problems at the cause.

**Smarter Loader**

First, avoid that the whole cache content is replaced. Your application requires that data is refreshed and not older than 10 minutes. But most likely, only a small portion of data actually was modified. In case the data was not modified, keep the existing object. Implement `reload` in your `CacheLoader`. I assume it is not used yet.

The default implementation of `reload` is:

```
  public ListenableFuture<V> reload(K key, V oldValue) throws Exception {
    checkNotNull(key);
    checkNotNull(oldValue);
    return Futures.immediateFuture(load(key));
  }
```

Make sure `equals` is available on the value and change it to:

```
  public ListenableFuture<V> reload(K key, V oldValue) throws Exception {
    checkNotNull(key);
    checkNotNull(oldValue);
    V newValue = load(key);
    if (oldValue.equals(newValue)) {
      newValue = oldValue;
    }
    return Futures.immediateFuture(newValue);
  }
```

This will still produce a lot of garbage but keeps the old generation and therefore avoids the full GC.

If your data source supports modification timestamps or hashes, there is a way to improve further. Here is a sketch of the idea:

```
  public ListenableFuture<V> reload(K key, V oldValue) throws Exception {
    checkNotNull(key);
    checkNotNull(oldValue);
    V newValue = loadIfModifiedNullOtherwise(key, oldValue.stamp);
    if (newValue == null) {
      newValue = oldValue;
    }
    return Futures.immediateFuture(newValue);
  }
```

An example is HTTP `if-modified-since`. If the data is still fresh in the cache, no data is transmitted.

**Use the cache features `expireAfterWrite` and `refreshAfterWrite`**

Refreshing at a fixed interval is always producing a spike. Instead of scheduled refresh use cache features and build the cache with:

```
   builder
     .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
     .refreshAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

This will have the advantages:

- It effectively randomizes the refresh activity because the load is triggered by user requests
- It will reduce the memory footprint. After 10 minutes of no access a cached item would be removed
- It most likely reduces the amount of load requests to the data source

It has a potential disadvantage, too. For the entries not accessed frequently, the access latency is getting higher, since the user request needs to wait for the load. In that area cache implementations could improve, but in most cases these features are good enough.

Please mind that Guava cache is no longer actively developed. Consider a more recent alternative.