# Caching objects causes frequent Major GC

Tags: java, caching, garbage-collection, jvm, caffeine-cache

In my project, I use **caffeine cache** for caching. The configuration is as follows.

```
 cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(6, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .maximumSize(50_0000.get())
                .recordStats()
                .build();
```

The cache is about 600m.

[image: heap]

Usage of read:

```
ReadOnlyHashTable v = itemPropsCache.getIfPresent(key);
```

If read miss, then load from redis

```
// load from redis ...
ReadOnlyHashTable table = new ReadOnlyHashTable('${redisVlue}');
itemPropsCache.setCache(key, table);
```

After checking the GC logs and JVM heap dump analysis, I found that the old age was growing consistently, resulting in full GC.

The following is my guess: because I set a 6-minute expiration, my cache will produce about 500m of garbage every six minutes in the old generation (because It will be promoted to the old age after reaching **MaxTenuringThreshold** through the younger generation, and then expire for cleaning).

I have tried CMS and G1 garbage collector, and it seems that they can not reach the ideal state.

CMS:

```
-server
-Xmx6g
-Xms6g
-XX:NewRatio=1
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15
-XX:SurvivorRatio=3
-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:MetaspaceSize=512m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-Xloggc:/export/Logs/gc.log
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
```

[image: CMS FullGC]

G1:

```
-server
-Xmx6g
-Xms6g
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:MetaspaceSize=512m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-Xloggc:/export/Logs/gc.log
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
```

[image: G1]

Is there any solution without adjusting the heap size and cache size?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please add code how you access and update the cache content? Is the cache size 500k or 500M?

Comment: There was a similar question, which I answered extensively: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71603019/tuning-the-gc-for-large-cache-refresh/71658845

Comment: @cruftex Hi cruftex, 500M, and I have updated code

Comment: GCs are not well designed for this workload. You might try to increase the young gen size to accommodate or the threads allocated for marking ([G1 tuning](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/gctuning/garbage-first-garbage-collector-tuning.html#GUID-0DD93225-0BCF-4605-B365-E9833F5BD2FC)). This case may better fit an off-heap cache like [OHC](https://github.com/snazy/ohc) or [ChronicleMap](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map), as you preallocate memory for reuse.

Comment: What is “the ideal state” you are trying to reach?

Comment: @Holger The less 'full gc' the better, it is better to reduce to one full GC in a day

Comment: How do you determine that you actually have a a Full GC? A G1GC Mixed collection is not a Full GC.